# Adding mirror links to a text

Tags: windows, markdown, web, archiving, hyperlink

I am looking for a program or script that runs on Microsoft Windows that can add mirror to any link present in a text formatted in Markdown.

Any price or license is fine.

E.g., if the input is

```
Two resources:

1. 10 videos, ~90 minutes each: [Advanced Topics  2015 (COMPM050/COMPGI13)
](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html) on Reinforcement Learning by David Silver (2015)

2. 455-page free  book:  [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (2nd Edition)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12568414) by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto (2016)
```

The output should be:

```
Two resources:

1. 10 videos, ~90 minutes each: [Advanced Topics  2015 (COMPM050/COMPGI13)
](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html)([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422233746/http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html)) on Reinforcement Learning by David Silver (2015)

2. 455-page free  book:  [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (2nd Edition)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12568414) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426234852/https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12568414)) by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto (2016)
```

For improved readability, the input is:

> Two resources:
>
> 1. 10 videos, ~90 minutes each: [Advanced Topics  2015 (COMPM050/COMPGI13)](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html)
>       on
>      Reinforcement Learning by David Silver (2015)
> 2. 455-page free  book:  [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (2nd Edition)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12568414) by Richard S.
>      Sutton and Andrew G. Barto (2016)

And the output should be something like:

> Two resources:
>
> 1. 10 videos, ~90 minutes each: [Advanced Topics  2015 (COMPM050/COMPGI13)](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html)
>      ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422233746/http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html))
>      on Reinforcement Learning by David Silver (2015)
> 2. 455-page free  book:  [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (2nd Edition)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12568414)
>      ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426234852/https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12568414))
>      by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto (2016)

Ideally one should be able to configure on which  [Web archiving initiative(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_archiving_initiatives)
to use.